# Middleware or seperate route to refresh jwt token?

Tags: rest, jwt

I'm currently trying to implement a JWT access/refresh token auth in my application.

Most people seem to have a dedicated POST route for refreshing the access token. Why would you not want to refresh the token in the middleware if the access token is expired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different application roles which may influence how you code things:

**WEB API**

REST APIs simply receive JWT access tokens, validate them and return a 401 if the JWT fails validation. eg if the token is expired. The API knows nothing about the client's OAuth details and never receives a refresh token. See [this code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts#L21).

**CLIENT UI**

Some types of UI application, eg mobile apps, use refresh tokens, and implement their own token refresh, as in [this code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/api/client/ApiClient.kt#L72):

- When a 401 is received from an API
- Try to refresh the access token
- Then retry the API call

**WEB BACK END**

If a web back end receives an access token from a Javascript app, and receives a 401 upon validating it, then the web back end can perform the refresh token step itself. This is because the web back end acts as the OAuth client, and, unlike APIs, has access to the client ID and secret.